# Can not execute update statement at toad for mysql but in other tools

Tags: mysql, sql, toad

I am using toad for mysql, but when I try to execute update the simple statement like
UPDATE `CART` SET `AID` = 10005 WHERE `ID` = 10007; it show me the error:

Cannot execute statement: impossible to write to binary log since BINLOG_FORMAT = STATEMENT and 
at least one table uses a storage engine limited to row-based logging. 
InnoDB is limited to row-logging when transaction isolation level is READ COMMITTED or READ UNCOMMITTED.

But the weird thing is it's working well in web application and other tools like HeidiSQL, Oracle sqldeveloper. 
Any one knows about this? is there any configuration of Toad for Mysql? thanks a lot.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Execute the following before your update statement:

```
SET SESSION TRANSACTION ISOLATION LEVEL READ UNCOMMITED
```

Comment: Thanks, I use SET SESSION TRANSACTION ISOLATION LEVEL REPEATABLE READ, it's working now. The toad for mysql open a transaction when open an sql file.

Comment: Please, mark question as answered if my response helped you fix your problem.

Comment: SET SESSION TRANSACTION ISOLATION LEVEL REPEATABLE READ  also solved my problem. Thanks for all